# Default seed PRNG in Java

Tags: java, random, prng

I was wondering what the default seed for the PRNG* behind `Math.random()` in Java is.  From what I understand the one in C is based upon the system clock.  So is it similar in Java?  Also, is the seed changed everytime `Math.random()` is called?

*PRNG = Pseudo Random Number Generator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you [Read The Fine Manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) it tells you

> When this method is first called, it creates a single new
>   pseudorandom-number generator, exactly as if by the expression
>
> `new java.util.Random()`
>
> This new pseudorandom-number generator is used
>   thereafter for all calls to this method and is used nowhere else.

Following up with `java.util.Random()`, the documentation says

> `public Random()`
>
> Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed
>   of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct
>   from any other invocation of this constructor.

The current implementation appears to be based on `System.nanoTime()` but could change and still be compliant with the documentation's contract.

As for changing the seed with every call, that's not how seeds work. PRNGs are seeded once, and then produce a sequence of values that evolve from that initial state. You shouldn't, and Java doesn't, keep re-seeding.

Comment: If we use something like `rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis( ));` it saying that this statement use the current time as seed, then if the current time is 20:01, so the seeding or starting value will be 20 or 01? or 2001?

Comment: @AHF [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) is your friend.

Answer (score 4):

You can always read the [code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/a8a2246158bc53414394b007cbf47413e62d942e/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Random.java).

`Math.random()` just uses an internal static Random object thats instantiated with no args...

```
       Random() {
90         this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
91     }
92 
93     private static long seedUniquifier() {
94         // L'Ecuyer, "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators of
95         // Different Sizes and Good Lattice Structure", 1999
96         for (;;) {
97             long current = seedUniquifier.get();
98             long next = current * 181783497276652981L;
99             if (seedUniquifier.compareAndSet(current, next))
100                return next;
101        }
102    }
103
104    private static final AtomicLong seedUniquifier = new AtomicLong(8682522807148012L);
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can see on [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29), the function uses a class called [Random()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29), wich uses a 48-bit seed, and generate a uniform distribution.