# How to convert java.util.random to an int

Tags: java, random

I am using java.util.random with a seed(new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())

- I need to convert this to a int(my business logic)
- I tried using the .nextInt(), but it doesn't help

> //my business logic--Below code is in a loop and is intended to
>   generate a different random number each time//

```
int randomNumber=(int) Math.floor(inputParam1 * (new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())).nextInt()));
```

Expected Ouput:A new random  number to  be generated each time, in int format

Actual Output:
 - with nextInt() it is generating the same number each time
 - without converting to Int, I am not able to use the 'Random'
   datatype with my int variable shown above

Comment: Post a complete minimal problem reproducing the issue. Tell precisely what output your expect, and what output you get instead.

Comment: Why are you creating a new `Random` just for that? `Math.random()` gives you a double from 0 to 1. And why are you casting the double to an int before assigning it to a double???

Comment: Depending on how fast a single loop takes, System.currentTimeMillis() might answer the same value, in which case the value returned by nextDouble will be the same.  I'd switch to getting the time in nanoseconds, and more important, to creating the Random instance just once and re-using it.

Comment: Please provide your expected input and output. It could be easier to provide a suggestion. However,  Math.random()  always gives a double from 0 to 1, so you are getting the double number.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart: With Math.random, when it runs to around a 10000 iterations, it tends to repeat , which is why I thought of using util.Random

Comment: [`Math.random()` uses `java.util.Random` internally](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#l745), so that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: @AbdurRahman jb nizet :Updated expected input and output

Comment: @ThomasBitonti: Trying the naneseconds approach now

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a new instance of Random each time you want to generate a Double.

You can create one instance and then call it whenever you need a new double.

```java
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

// loop starts here

  double randomNumber = Math.floor(inputParam1 * rand.nextDouble());

// If you want an integer up to inputParam1 as it seems, you can do:

  int randomInt = (int) randomNumber;
```

You can also use `Math.random()` as someone already suggested.

Comment: Chaning the nanoseconds as per one of the inputs above and also using your suggestion of declaring once and calling it multiple times.Will keep you updated

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you casting it to int

double randomNumber= new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextDouble();
this will give a random double number between 0 and 1

Comment: Updated code above, I meant to cast to an int. Confusion was because was using Math.random() and casting to Double earlier

Comment: whats the value of  inputParam1 ?

Comment: It will be a 2-digit int value(eg:56,72 etc)

Comment: int randomNumber=(int) Math.floor(inputParam1  * (new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())).nextInt());

Comment: Thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

Converting below code to int makes no sense.

```
Math.floor(inputParam1 * (new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())).nextDouble()))
```

And please, check this answer [Using Random Number Generator with Current Time vs Without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277110/using-random-number-generator-with-current-time-vs-without)

The most important part from above link:

> If you want your random sequences to be the same between runs you can
>   specify a seed.

Comment: Updated code above, I meant to cast to an int. Confusion was because was using Math.random() and casting to Double earlier.

Comment: Will check the link post trying out some inputs suggested above,