# Distribution of Random Numbers

Tags: java, random, uniform-distribution

I have two options of code:

**Option 1**

```
int myFunc() {
  return new Random().nextInt();
}
```

Or:

**Option 2**

```
private static final Random random = new Random();

int myFunc() {
  return random.nextInt();
}
```

I understand that `option 2` is more idiomatic. I am wondering about the validity of `option 1`.

In `option 1` I will only ever use the first number generated by a given seed. In `option 2` I choose a seed and generate `n` numbers using that seed. IIUC the guarantees on randomness are on this use case.

My question is, therefore, if I call `option 1` many times are there any guarantees on the uniformity of the distribution of the output?

Comment: go with option 3: `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()`. Also you're wrong about randoms at the same time, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20060801/995891 it's not only using time to initialize.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of this. I'll update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My real question is whether option 1 is mathematically valid.

Lets start with option 2.  The random number generator used by `java.util.Random` is specified in the javadoc as follows:

> The class uses a 48-bit seed, which is modified using a linear congruential formula. (See Donald Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2, Section 3.2.1.)

and there is more specific detail in the various methods' javadocs.

But the point is that we are using a sequence generated by a linear congruential formula, and such formulae have a significant degree of auto-correlation ... which could be problematic.

Now with option 1, you are using a different `Random` instance with a new seed each time, and applying one round of the LC formula.  Thus you are getting a sequence of numbers that are likely to be autocorrelated with the seeds.  However, the seeds are generated in different ways, depending on the Java version.

Java 6 does this:

```
 public Random() { this(++seedUniquifier + System.nanoTime()); }
 private static volatile long seedUniquifier = 8682522807148012L;
```

... which is not very random at all.  If you created `Random` instances at a constant interval, the seeds are likely to be closely spaced, and therefore the sequence of random numbers produced by your option #1 are liable to be auto-correlated.

By contrast, Java 7 and 8 do this:

```
 public Random() {
     this(seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime());
 }

 private static long seedUniquifier() {
     // L'Ecuyer, "Tables of Linear Congruential Generators of
     // Different Sizes and Good Lattice Structure", 1999
     for (;;) {
         long current = seedUniquifier.get();
         long next = current * 181783497276652981L;
         if (seedUniquifier.compareAndSet(current, next))
             return next;
     }
 }

 private static final AtomicLong seedUniquifier
     = new AtomicLong(8682522807148012L);
```

The sequence of seeds produced by the above are likely be a much better approximation to (true) randomness.  That probably makes your option #1 superior to option #2.

The downside of your option #1 in Java 6 through 8 is that the `System.nanoTime()` probably call involves a system call.  That is relatively expensive.

---

So the short answer is that it is Java version specific which of option #1 and option #2 produces better quality "random" numbers ... from a mathematical perspective.

In both cases, the distribution of numbers will be uniform over a large enough sample size, though I'm not sure it is meaningful to talk about probability distributions when the process is deterministic.

However, neither approach would be suitable as a "crypto strength" random number generator.

Comment: Thanks, that is very interesting. You mentioned that the System.nanoTime is expensive. What would happen if you just use the seedUniquifier as the seed instead of calling the default constructor? I can calculate seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime() once at startup and then use that as my initial seed to avoid getting the same sequence each run. Will results then be autocorrelated?

Comment: *"You mentioned that the System.nanoTime is expensive."* - **Relatively** expensive.

Comment: *"I can calculate seedUniquifier() ^ System.nanoTime() once at startup and then use that as my initial seed to avoid getting the same sequence each run. Will results then be autocorrelated?"* - Yes.  I think.  But you can test this.  Google for "test autocorrelation" for some leads.

Answer (score 10):

Quick Code:

```
// For occasional tasks that just need an average quality random number
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
threadPool.execute( () -> {
  ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(); // Fast and unique!
} );


// For SecureRandom, high quality random number
final Random r = new SecureRandom();
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
threadPool.execute( () -> {
  r.nextInt(); // sun.security.provider.NativePRNG uses singleton.  Can't dodge contention.
} );


// Apache Common Math - Mersenne Twister - decent and non-singleton
int cpu = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( cpu );
Map<Thread, RandomGenerator> random = new WeakHashMap<>( cpu, 1.0f );

executor.execute( ()-> {
   RandomGenerator r;
   synchronized ( random ) { // Get or create generator.
      r = random.get( Thread.currentThread() );
      if ( r == null ) random.put( Thread.currentThread(), r = new MersenneTwister() );
   }
   r.nextInt( 1000 );
} );
```

---

Explanation:

1. **Two `Random` of same seed will yield same numbers.**

   1. Thus we will focus on whether we can guarantee different seeds.
2. **In theory, `new Random()` in each thread does not guarantee different seed.**

   1. new Random is seeded by [nanoTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) and a "unique" number.
   2. The number is not guaranteed unique because its calculation is not synchronized.
   3. As for nanoTime, it guarantees to be "at least at good as [currentTimeMillis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--)"
   4. currentTimeMillis does not guarantee anything and can be [pretty](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4423429) [coarse](http://www.javamex.com/faq/timing.shtml).
   5. In real life, the two times are the same only on [old linux systems and Win 98](https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks).
3. **In practice, `new Random()` in each thread basically always get different seeds.**

   1. Creating thread is expensive.  Mine creates 1 per 50,000ns. And that's [not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5483467/893578) [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371508/893578).
   2. 50µs is way above nanoTime's common granularities of up to [a few ten ns](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/).
   3. The unique number calculation (1.2) is also fast, so getting same number is very rare.
   4. Use [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) to create a [thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) to avoid the heavy new thread overhead.
4. **zapl [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242833/distribution-of-random-numbers#comment63906933_38242833) `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()`. Great idea.**

   1. It does not create new `Random`, but it is also a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).
   2. It generate a new random for each call thread as that thread's seed.
   3. It is built to be very fast in multi-thread. (See notes below.)
   4. It is statically seeded by `SecureRandom`, which produce better quality random numbers.
5. **"uniformally distributed" is just one small part of [randomness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_randomness) [tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778718/how-to-test-random-numbers/27160683#27160683).**

   1. `Random` is [somewhat uniform](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/lcg_bit_positions.shtml), and its result can be [predicted](https://jazzy.id.au/2010/09/20/cracking_random_number_generators_part_1.html) given just two values.
   2. [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) guarantees [this won't happens](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/securerandom.shtml). (i.e. cryptographically strong)
   3. There is no risk of seed collision if you create a new `SecureRandom` in each thread.
   4. But currently its source is [single thread](https://plumbr.eu/blog/locked-threads/shooting-yourself-in-the-foot-with-random-number-generators) anyway, no parallel generation.
   5. For a good RNG that supports multi-thread, find [external help](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+high+quality+random+number+generator) like Apache Common's [MT](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/MersenneTwister.html).

> Note: Implementation details deduced from Java 8 source code.
>   Future Java version may change; for example, `ThreadLocalRandom` is using [`sun.misc.Unsafe`](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-sunmiscunsafe) to store the seeds,
>   which [may be removed](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2952869/java-platform/understanding-sun-misc-unsafe.html) in Java 9 forcing ThreadLocalRandom to find a new way to work without contention.

Comment: Thanks. You say "new Random() in every new thread does not guarantee uniform distribution." Can you explain more. Why does the performance of the clock have anything to do with the randomness? As zapl said, Random gives different seeds even when called twice with the exact same time. Why does the time to start a thread negatively affect the randomness of the distribution? Can you give a source.

Comment: @BenjyKessler In theory, creating two Random at the exact same time, in a perfect parallel execution, should yield two Randoms with same seed, as of Java 8 u92.  But "exact same time" and "perfect parallel execution" is hard.  What I want to say is because Thread takes relatively long time to create, the nanoTime deviation alone will make sure your Random get different seed in practice (point 2), even when not guaranteed (point 1).

Comment: I'm sorry, I think my question isn't clear. The way a RNG works is it converts one random number to another random number. So starting from one "random" number you can generate as many "random" numbers as you want. The key is that you started with a randomish number and the randomness of the output is dependant on the randomness of the seed. In my case I am using a different model. Instead of starting with one "random" seed I am starting with `n` highly correlated seeds. My question is, do I still get any guarantees on uniformity (uniformity, not randomness).

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

There are no guarantees on the properties of the distribution of numbers that will be produced by Option 1.  As has been made clear in other answers, the implementation of the constructor for `java.util.Random` depends on the system time.  Therefore, in order to make a guarantee on the properties of the distribution of numbers you get with Option 1, you would need to be able to make guarantees about the distribution of numbers produced by the calls your program makes to get the system time on any platform where the program will be running.

With option 2, however, there are mathematical guarantees that can be made about the distribution of numbers that will be produced during one execution of the program.  With a linear congruential generator (the pseudorandom number generation algorithm used by `java.util.Random`) some of the properties of randomness are not quite as good as with other algorithms, but the distribution is guaranteed to be relatively uniform.

This does not necessarily mean that Option 1 cannot serve your purposes.  It depends on what you are doing.

Comment: By invoking a new RNG at every call he is invoking the seed algorithm to kick off the first number. Is the seeding algorithm itself uniform across the range? Unlikely. ["As can be seen, given two integers from java.util.Random, we can predict all future generated integers."](https://jazzy.id.au/2010/09/20/cracking_random_number_generators_part_1.html) He is not using an RNG, he is using a bad seed algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Java initializes the random seed with `System.nanoTime()` and a sequential counter. This gives somewhat a guarantee that the seed will be different for each invocation, although I would refrain from calling it cryptographically secure.

From the performance point of view - do you really expect locking on internal state of Random in option 1 to have a larger performance hit then all of the following:

- accessing and incrementing volatile long
- getting the current system time ([which is quite expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052316/why-is-system-nanotime-way-slower-in-performance-than-system-currenttimemill))
- dynamic allocation
- another object for garbage collection

My suggestion will be to do benchmarks of your real application to find out, but I expect option 1 to be the slowest of all three.

Comment: Thanks. I'm more interested in knowing about the "cryptographically secure" aspect. The efficiency was just one rationale I was giving for why to use option 1. My real question is whether option 1 is mathematically valid.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html "Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance." and "Instances of java.util.Random are not cryptographically secure. Consider instead using SecureRandom to get a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator for use by security-sensitive applications."

Comment: I guess my question would remain the same for `SecureRandom`. Would creating a new one every time and generating only one instance from a given seed, still be secure? Or would it be so correlated with the choice of seeds (the times when the function was called) that randomness is lost.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience,  the best balance between good distribution and performance is given by using something like the "Messerne Twister" generator  [(see in Apache Commons)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/random/MersenneTwister.html) .   For an even fancier solution,  see [this](http://ubld.it/products/truerng-hardware-random-number-generator/).